# vsftpd сделать файл доступным только для чтения при открытии его каким либо пользователем

Tags: ftp, iptables, vsftpd

Есть следующая ситуация:
на сервер vsftpd подключаются два пользователя. Один из них открывает файл и производит в нем какие-либо изменения. Второй пользователь открывает этот же файл, после чего первый сохраняет свои изменения. Далее второй пользователь сохраняет свои изменения и мы получаем ситуацию, при которой изменения пользователя 1 пропадают. Вопрос: можно ли при открытии файла каким либо пользователем сделать этот файл доступным только для чтения всем остальным пользователям, пока пользователь 1 его не закроет? Если да, то как это реализовать?

Comment: vsftpd - обычный FTP-сервер. "Открыть" на нём файл попросту невозможно - FTP-протокол ничего подобного не умеет. Пользователь загружает файл к себе и открывает на редактирование локальную копию, причём сервер вообще не в курсе, что там делается с отправленной им копией, и делается ли вообще. При сохранении - пользователь просто удаляет старую версию и записывает новую. Никакого редактирования протокол не предоставляет - get, del, put да append. И никакого "пока не закроет" нет в принципе.

Comment: Единственное что приходит в голову, в кроне сделать по расписанию скрипт который будет парсить лог VSFTPD и если там есть скажем операция скачивания файла, то менять на нем права, так чтобы другие его не смогли редактировать до обратной операции. но сложность тут в том что файл то могут назад и не залить, а просто скачали и посмотрели. блокировок в фтп нет, он предназначен изначально для обмена, а не для совместной работы над файлами.